# Go back to PageModel navigartion from PageRenderer

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, navigation, freshmvvm

I got a little issue, I don't know how to go back to my PageModel and continue the navigation after using a PageRenderer.
I'm trying to implement FacebookLogin on my app, so I'm using a pageRenderer in order to set the facebook authentification page and use it to get back user information. The issue is that when the user press login, I process all his informations and so on, but, I absolutely don't know what to do after that to continue my navigation.

thanks

**edit**

Here what I tried in one of my class :

```
var mainContainer = new FreshMasterDetailNavigationContainer(NavigationContainerNames.MainContainer);
        mainContainer.Init("Menu");
        mainContainer.AddPage<ActivityFeedListPageModel>("ActivityFeed", new User());
        mainContainer.AddPage<ProfilePageModel>("Profile", new User());
        App.Current.MainPage = mainContainer;
```

After that it's said in the documentation tu use `CoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation(NavigationContainerNames.MainContainer);` but I don't know how to do it from here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try it with two separate navigation stacks. One for the login process and one for the main application. You can see an example of this by the original author of FreshMVVM:

[LoginPage with FreshMVVM](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70494/loginpage-with-freshmvvm)

It's also worth checking the GitHub page where the Navigation service is also discussed.

[Switcing out NavigationStacks on the Xamarin.Forms MainPage](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm#switching-out-navigationstacks-on-the-xamarinforms-mainpage)

---

**Edit:** Related to your update, here's what you can try.

[CoreMethods](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/d1c9e1896e4040388ef43203df1254787bc84f36/src/FreshMvvm/FreshBasePageModel.cs#L40) is a member of the FreshBasePageModel which all your PageModel's should already inherit. This means that you can call [SwitchOutRootNavigation](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/d1c9e1896e4040388ef43203df1254787bc84f36/src/FreshMvvm/PageModelCoreMethods.cs#L182) within any of your PageModels.

Comment: That's what i did, i created one container for the login and one container for the rest of the app. I switch stack when the login is completed and it's working well for email login. My problem is in the facebook login part, after the user entered his infos I don't know how to go back to my pagemodel navigation to switch once the user login is completed

Comment: @RémiHirtz I updated my answer related to the edit on your original post.